# Objective C Header with Implementation

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, interface, header

So someone gave me their code to work on, and I noticed that their header files (specifically ViewController.h) have not only declared fields, but have initialized them. Take a look:

[image]

The funny thing is, this is all in my header (.h) file, but it's still compiling! Isn't this not allowed?

My implementation file (ViewController.m) imports this header file, so I know that it's getting compiled. Why is the compiler not saying this is wrong?

Comment: Please post code, not images.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is a structure declaration and its syntax is correct as you posted abouve so there is nothing wrong here.